# RegEx to check 3 or more consecutive occurrences of a character

Tags: php, regex

I want to check an input string to validate a proper text.

a. I want the users to allow to writer alphanumeric characters including period, comma, hyphen and round bracket ()

b. However, i dont want the users to enter a NUMBER with 3 or more digits together. eg: 12 is allowed while 185 is NOT.

c. I dont want the users to enter strings like "............." or "----------" or "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" or "bbbbbbbb" etc.

Please suggest the regular expression for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$
```

It uses the negative lookahead `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` to ensure that there is no group of 3 repetitions of any of the characters.

Then it uses the regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$` to ensure that the string is made of just alphabets, numbers, period, comma, parenthesis and hyphen.

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/B4JtF6ly6n)

Comment: I used this 

`code` if(preg_match("(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$", $about_you)){   
   echo 'Invalid Text';
  }
`code`
and it throws the following error:
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '^' in E:\Projects\www\scripts\test-f.php on line 33

line 33 begis at if(preg_match("(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$", $about_you)){

Comment: Try: `if(preg_match("/(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$/", $about_you)){`

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work. Though I am not getting any parsing error now but the expression is  unable to matach the string as it should be `code` if(preg_match("/(?!.*(.)\1{2})^[a-zA-Z0-9.,()-]*$/", $about_you)){
   echo "error";
  }`code`

Comment: The above regex do not match special characters. `/(?!.*(.)\1{2})^.*$/` This one checks any 3 or more consecutive characters.

Answer (score 1):

Most regex libs support the folloing:
`/(.)\1{2,}/`

where `\1` is a a backreference