# How to check if a string contains 3 or more consecutive number

Tags: php

How to check if a string contains 3 or more consecutive number (We have to ignore this check for the number between the word starting with "border" and ending with ";")

Example : "border1234;"  --> check should not be done for this string

Actually i am able to check if the string contains 3 or more consecutive numbers but i am not able to ignore this check for numbers between "border" and ";" phrases.

### Code i used

```
if (preg_match("/\d{3}/", $myString, $matches) > 0 ){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you put some code example?

Comment: downvote because I couldn't see any clear informations, try to put your php code, Thanks

Comment: Run a `regex` match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to check 3 or more consecutive occurances of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918809/regex-to-check-3-or-more-consecutive-occurances-of-a-character)

Comment: Hi Hardik , Appreciate your quick response. but i dont think this would solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
/(?=.*\d{3,})(?!.*border\d{3,};)/
```

It matches any string that contains 3 or more consecutive digits except if those digits are between "border" and ";"